# Can I base a AWS Sagemaker multi model endpoint on a model collection (from AWS Model Registry) instead of an S3 URI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I implemented a multi model endpoint with custom image following this example: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/multi_model_bring_your_own/multi_model_endpoint_bring_your_own.ipynb.

This worked out well! But I do not like that I have to hand over a S3 path when I create the multi model object using the sm_client.create_model() function (more specifically the "ModelDataUrl" in this documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_model.html#) . Instead I would like to hand over a model collection from the AWS Sagemaker registry.

Is there a way to base a multi model endpoint on a collection from sagemaker registry? In my opinion this would make a lot of sense as the model registry functions as a layer in between the actual storage in S3 und the deployment of endpoints.

I was expecting to find some way to hand over a model collection instead of an s3 path

Comment: If it's a model you've registered on the model registry, I think you can use the ModelPackageName parameter (model versions are necessarily ModelPackages).

Comment: But then it would be a single model. And the whole sense of this multi model endpoint is that it can use many different models. So it should be a collection and not a ModelPackage, right?

Comment: The way MME is currently structured, it's mandatory providing an S3 URL bucket with all the model data under that common location. You could manipulate model registry such that all registered models are under the same S3 location.